# 5 V to 4 V and a transistor

Tags: voltage, transistors

I don't now much electronics, so I got myself a project to learn more. I have a 5 V source, something needing 4 V to run, and a way to send a HIGH to a transistor to get the 4 V thing running.

For what I can find, a transistor should shave off around 0.2-0.6 V. However, on both my logical and physical tests, it removes much more. Am I missing something? Do I need to use another component? I'm early in the learning process, so I might be doing something completely stupid.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Measure across your 5V source.  It is common for supplies to reduce in voltage when you draw too much current.  This is likely such a case.  Check amperage or power specs of motor and power supply.

Comment: A BJT transistor would drop 0.2 to 0.6V, at some rated current, when used properly. It is unknown which transistor is in your simulation, but simulated transistors also don't burn up and get damaged by heat, as it is dissipating over 2.5 watts. Try to read about basic transistor circuits first, then try them in simulators and in real life.

Comment: Assuming your 5 V supply is solid, tell us what diode-connected BJT you are using, both in practice and in that simulation diagram. If it is a small signal BJT, there will be quite a drop though I don't think it would well survive what your simulation is showing. (2.42 V * 1.29 A = 3.1 W.) Your pass transistor, even working right, will dissipate about 1.3 W. And for that you'll need a diff-pair of BJTs as an error amplifier for regulation. What are you willing to do? Do you want an IC? Or a discrete circuit?

Answer (score 1):

1A is quite a bit of current. Here is an appropriate transistor used as you suggest:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9R4Q7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even so it drops 850mV or so.

If you put a smallish transistor such as a BC547 or 2N4401 in place of the TIP31 power transistor it will have a much higher drop (and will quickly emit smoke, popping noises and such like).

It would be cheaper to use a 3A diode such as 1N5403:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0mQYB.png)</sup>

Comment: Obsolete 1N5408

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 [from one distributor and one of many manufacturers](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/1N5408G-T/128597) there are 543,791 pieces in stock that can be delivered tomorrow. This is the very definition of a jellybean part.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBki.png OK ok :)

Comment: I think that people have been specifying and stocking higher voltage parts since there is little to no difference in price, and you can always substitute a higher PRV part for a lower one.

Comment: I worry about the lack of discussion on design specs before jumping to solutions for beginners and lack of links to question simulations, while Sheriff Sam is doing his duty.

Comment: There is frequently a dichotomy between answering the question(s) presented ("Am I missing something". "Do I need to use another component? " or trying to find an optimal solution to whatever problem the OP may or may not be trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Congrats!, Yes you smoked your 1st transistor on a simulator.  (epoxy smoke is toxic)  Vbe=2.42V and Ic = 1A is incorrect. Find a better simulator.

Motors need to have all parameters defined especially DCR.
This uses a power 1W resistor and 1W transistor, hFE=30.

[image]

Remember this.

1. Never assume anything you see works, **when designing any switch.**
   First define for on off, V input range Max/min,  switch R or allowed voltage drop , load max current, compute V*I(t)=P and logic polarity.
2. All transistor switches are inverting, but you can invert them again by switching the low side to 0V.
3. Emitter Followers are good current buffers (unidirectional) but are not "switches" and may react poorly to inductive loads.
4. All reactive loads need switch surge protection, On for Caps, Off for inductors
5. Always define the purpose of a switch and not just "something" and the load impedance and/or reference datashseet.

Comment: Vbe = 2.5 V, Vce = 2.5 V, and according to that simulator Ic = 1 A (the question author's simulator above). I would recommend to use the Falstad simulator (like the author of the answer has done in the second screenshot). Falstad is easy to use and very accurate.

Comment: @ee_student  I agree and have been using for many years. The best tool is the one you know how to use and what the assumptions and limitations are.  e.g. std diode/transistor model or custom.. ideal voltage source or add ESR, ESL with discretes, ideal Cap or same